# Linq: Union on two tables with date and datetime columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 entities that I want to union in the database:

```
public class Event
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
}

public class ClosingDay
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime DatumVon { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see, the columns are slightly different, Datum is a DateTime and datumVon is a date type. Which makes them look slightly different in the database as the project is a codefirst approach.

so now I want to create a linq statement to join these two columns (in the database, I cannot do this in memory):

```
var tmp =
(
    from s in _context.ClosingDay
    select new CalendarDTO
    {
        Datum = Convert.ToDateTime(s.DatumVon),
        Name = Convert.ToString(s.Name)
    }
).Concat(
    from t in _context.Event
    select new CalendarDTO
    {
        Datum = Convert.ToDateTime(t.Datum),
        Name = Convert.ToString(t.Name)
    }
);
```

where the CalendarDTO looks like this:

```
public class CalendarDTO
{
    public DateTime DatumVon { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It works if I only set the Name in the CalendarDTO, but the union of the date fields does not work, despite the convert.toDateTime

I keep getting the error

```
Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.
```

Do you have any idea how to make it work without doing the union inmemory?

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to Entities can't translate `Convert.ToDateTime` to SQL code. But you can use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime) instead:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var tmp =
(
    from s in _context.ClosingDay
    select new CalendarDTO
    {
        DatumVon = s.DatumVon,
        Name = s.Name
    }
).Concat(
    from t in _context.Event
    select new CalendarDTO
    {
        DatumVon = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Datum),
        Name = t.Name
    }
);
```

> When used as part of a LINQ to Entities query, this method invokes the canonical TruncateTime EDM function to return the given date with the time portion cleared.

Note that `DateTime` itself can contain data of both `date` and `datetime` types. That is, EF automatically mapped the `date` type to a `DateTime` object with the time portion set to `00:00:00`.

Comment: Thank you! is there another way? Because I actually need the timespan in t.Datum

Answer (score 1):

Wow. through sheer luck I found this weird "solution":

```
var tmp =
(
    from s in _context.ClosingDay
    select new CalendarDTO
    {
        DatumVon = (DateTime)(object)s.DatumVon,
        Name = s.Name
    }
).Concat(
    from t in _context.Event
    select new CalendarDTO
    {
        DatumVon = (DateTime)(object)t.Datum,
        Name = t.Name
    }
);
```

This works. I wouldn't recommend it (because I believe that eventually after an EF Update it will no longer work) but it works for now.